# How is the rule of thumb to know whether to use "-or-" or "-our-"?

Tags: spelling

For years I kept struggling with differentiating between whether a particular word is using -or- or -our-. These are some examples of words that I'm often having problems with:

- Behaviour vs behavior
- Favourite vs favorite
- Colour vs color
- Neighbour vs neighbor

More often than not, my spellcheck always highlights such words even when I typed them proudly, thinking that I got it right this time. For some time, I thought I should always use only -or-. But then the spellcheck highlights some incorrect words. Then I thought I should always use only -our-. But the spellcheck highlights other incorrect words. What is the rule of thumb to know which one to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *-our* spellings are more often used in the UK (and some other countries), while the *-or* spellings are more often used in the U.S. (and some other countries). Both are correct, but you should probably be consistent. Here is a brief discussion of the issue: https://qz.com/596395/the-case-of-the-missing-us-in-american-english/

You can probably reduce some of the spellcheck warnings if you set the langauge to U.S. or British English and stay consistent.

Comment: Ah, I see so this is because of the differences between Americans and English. The included article really helps. Thanks!